# Reduce 0-1 knapsack prob. to a SAT prob

Tags: algorithm

Is there any way to reduce the [0-1 knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#0.2F1_knapsack_problem) to a [SAT problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#Unrestricted_satisfiability_.28SAT.29) in Conjunctive Norm Form?

Comment: If you're trying to prove that the 0-1 knapsack problem is NP-hard, then the reduction needs to go in the other direction...

Comment: @j_random_hacker No I'm not proving it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always work out the digital circuits necessary to implement adders and comparators and then turn the result of that into conjunctive normal form. You can get circuits into CNF form without expanding them exponentially by making up intermediate variables which represent the outputs of small sections of circuit.

Each node of a circuit amounts to a=f(b, c) where a is the output, b and c the input, and f is some simple function like & or |. You can create a CNF function that is true only when a really is the result of f(b, c) and it can't be too unwieldy, because it is a function on only three variables.

You can rewrite any circuit into a large number of terms of the form a=f(b, c) and all you have to do with the CNF versions of these is to AND them all together. Assuming you want to solve for the output being true, you then just stick on the output variable as the final component of that big AND.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I think `f` would be non-trivial?

Comment: The functions f I am talking about here are the basic binary functions of 2 input bits. There are only 16 of them, none very complicated, and you actually only need one, NAND(a,b) = ~(a & b) to build every possible digital circuit from them. See e.g. http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/hp/staff/dmb/courses/dig2/5_Adder.pdf for examples of building an adder from binary logic. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate

Comment: I think you meant Tseitin transformation, that's the part I missed. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know of it by that name until you mentioned it so thanks for that - when I read of it either it wasn't given a name or I forgot it.